# How is a carpet plot for aircraft sizing constructed?

Tags: aircraft-design

Generally, Carpet Plots are constructed to find out an optimal design which will satisfy all the performance needs and is least in weight & cost.

I want to know how to construct such a carpet plot.
I have seen lines of constant weight in many carpet plots with T/W and W/S in the Y and X-axis respectively. But, I don't know how they constructed that constant weight line.

If there are some good references for constructing these types of sizing plots, please let me know.

Comment: Any book about general airplane design describes in a clear way carpet plots and how to plot them. You can find for example a list of books in [this answer of mine](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/94939/how-can-i-calculate-the-total-drag-of-the-entire-airplane/94957#94957)

Answer (score 1):

You might check out [this package](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40831-carpet-plot-toolkit?) on the Matlab file exchange.

Set up a matrix or a grid of T/W and W/S.  Then do your calculations and calculate weight, operating cost, or whatever metric you want for each T/W, W/S in the matrix.

Then, use a contour plotting routine to generate isolines (isoline means a line of constant value).  Basically, the contour routine will interpolate from the values in your grid to find the location of your isoline.

Using contour plots like this is a very powerful technique to effectively 'invert' functions that are otherwise not invertible.  This is a pretty direct application of the implicit function theorem f(x,y)=0.

The carpet plot toolkit linked above has some routines to help transform 'normal' contour lines onto a carpet plot.  I believe the blue contours and also the red and green constraints depicted in the example were evaluated with a contour algorithm.